# What is the correct approach to customize design of Material UI components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, material-ui, frontend

I am looking forward to start the development of new application. UX team has provided me the atomic design system. I am looking forward to use material ui as the base component and customize the whole MUI library to change its styling.

Can someone suggest me the correct approach to customize MUI components.

MUI documents suggest various ways but should I select styled components, css props or theming to customize the whole library.

MUI docs also says that styled components should not be used with SSR applications.

Please help me with the correct approach.